# Gitlab ISSUE API: Order by relative_position - do not show same result like "manual" sorting on UI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to use the gitlab API for [issues](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#list-group-issues) with the soring `manual` like on the issue list UI on gitlab.com.

I have used the attribute / parameter
API: Order by relative_position

I tryied that `{{base_url}}/groups/{{my_group_id}}/issues?order_by=relative_position`

**base_url**: https://gitlab.com/api/v4
**my_group_id**: a group id (number) from my project / company

The `order_by=relative_position` parameter does not produce the same order as “manual” ordering in the UI, more or less the parameter seems to be ignored totally. Other parameters I have tried worked.

I found that here, from ~ 2019, on [GitLab Forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/api-order-by-relative-position/49368). Also there is no answer ...
I also found [API attribute/call to get Issues by sort order in Boards](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21297)

If the REST-API do not work, I am also happy about an solution / idea with GRAPHQL of gitlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was **NOT** able to fix it with `REST API` but with `GRAPH QL`.

The command below uses `{MY_COMPANY}` and `{MY_GROUP}`, just replace it with your `group`.

```json
{
  group(fullPath: "{MY_COMPANY}/{MY_GROUP}") {
    issues(sort: RELATIVE_POSITION_ASC, state: opened) {
      nodes {
        title
        id
        iid
        weight
        labels { nodes {title} }
      }  
    }  
  }
}
```

Here an example for the gitlab **project**, not group

```json
{
  project(fullPath: "gitlab-org/gitlab") {
    issues(sort: RELATIVE_POSITION_ASC, state: opened) {
      nodes {
        title
        id
        iid
        weight
        labels { nodes {title} }
      }  
    }  
  }
}
```

- [Gitlab GraphQL Docu](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/)
- [Gitlab GraphQL Explorer](https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to make it work is using `sort=asc` and `order_by=relative_position` parameter, that way all tickets were returned in the correct (UI) order. However, setting `sort=desc` didn't do the trick